# Using reflection to delete childObject inside parentObject in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to use reflection to remove the reference of a childObject inside a parent object.

```
public class ParentObject{
    public object ChildObject {get;set;}
}
```

---

```
/* Implementation */ 

ParentObject parentObject = new ParentObject();
object childObject = new Object();

//I set this using reflection (PropertyInfo SetValue operation)
parentObject.ChildObject = childObject ;

... 
//I want to remove the reference to the child object using reflection
RemoveObjectUsingReflection(parentObject, childObject);

Assert.IsNull(parentObject.ChildObject); //returns true
```

---

```
function RemoveObjectUsingReflection(object parentObject, object childObject)
{
   //Appreciate your help here
}
```

Comment: At this time, I am adding another parameter (name of the childObject property in parentObject) to the RemoveObjectUsingReflection method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I properly understood what you meant by "remove", simply set it to `null`:

```
var property = parentObject.GetType().GetProperty("ChildObject"); // get the property
property.SetValue(parentObject, null, null);
```

It does make me wonder why you need reflection for this though.

Comment: If he wanted to do that he could just do parentObject.ChildObject = null; and not use reflection.

Comment: I do not know if childObject object refers to "ChildObject" property. I only have an instance of childObject

Comment: So... what is your problem _exactly_? Because my crystal ball is currently out of order.

Comment: well.. try mine. I have two objects through reflection, the only information i have is one is a parent and other is a child. I need to remove the reference of the child inside the parent. Suggest me some ideas.